# I am trying to use multiple pivot in sql but not getting the output as i want

Tags: sql-server, pivot-table

[Below image is the output i am getting but i want the output to be in one line for the same property and tenant.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzWEM.png)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzWEM.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hzsu.png**strong text**

[Second picture shows you the query i am using. Can anyone help me to correct the output and let me know what is wrong in my query][2]

Comment: please do not post image. Use text

Comment: Please create and link a DB fiddle to allow people to replicate the issue.

Comment: You can only pivot one set of columns per basic statement. Pivoting multiple sets of columns essentially involves much repetition of code via unions (or joins). Have you considered conditional aggregration instead?